# custom functions with group_by tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I missing something in my understanding how group_by is working in tidyverse. Example will clarify:

I have created following function, it takes few arguments and calculates optimal weights inside tibble (probably not prettiest but seems to work):

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
library(tidyverse)

weights_fun <- function(data_tbl, objective, constraint){
  cols <- c("objective", "constraint")
  linear.dt <- data_tbl %>% select_(.dots = cols)
  lp.mod <- make.lp(0, NROW(linear.dt))
  set.objfn(lp.mod, linear.dt$amount)
  lp.control(lp.mod,sense="max")
  add.constraint(lp.mod, linear.dt$duration, "=", 6)
  add.constraint(lp.mod, rep(1, nrow(linear.dt)), "=", 1)
  set.bounds(lp.mod, upper = rep(0.4, nrow(linear.dt)))
  set.bounds(lp.mod, lower = rep(0.10, nrow(linear.dt)))
  solve(lp.mod)
  weights <- round(get.variables(lp.mod), 4)
  return(weights)
}
```

this functions works nicely when I have just one group in tibble. My way of creating functions is that try to get it work by testing on one and hopefully it will work when I slice data later.

```
weights_fun(one_group, "amount", "duration")
one_group$weights <- weights_fun(one_group, "amount", "duration")


  # A tibble: 5 x 6
        date country bucket   amount duration weights
      <date>   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2006-01-31      AT     B1 4844.500  1.48475  0.1000
2 2006-01-31      AT     B2 8601.000  3.67500  0.1911
3 2006-01-31      AT     B3 8518.400  5.39900  0.4000
4 2006-01-31      AT     B4 6469.550  6.99950  0.1000
5 2006-01-31      AT     B5 7804.533 10.96133  0.2089
```

Then I hoped that I could use mutate to create new column of weights to my multiple groups as following, but I get error:

```
three_groups %>% 
  group_by(date, country) %>% 
  mutate(weights = weights_fun(., "amount", "duration"))

Adding missing grouping variables: `date`, `country`
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `weights` must be length 5 (the group size) or one, not 15
```

So what am I missing? Why is my function returning 15 and not 5 for each group?

DATA:

```
one_group <- structure(list(date = structure(c(13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 
13179), class = "Date"), country = c("AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", 
"AT"), bucket = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"), amount = c(4844.5, 
8601, 8518.4, 6469.55, 7804.53333333333), duration = c(1.48475, 
3.675, 5.399, 6.9995, 10.9613333333333)), .Names = c("date", 
"country", "bucket", "amount", "duration"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

three_groups <- structure(list(date = structure(c(13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 
13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 13179, 
13179, 13179), class = "Date"), country = c("AT", "AT", "AT", 
"AT", "AT", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", 
"BE"), bucket = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B1", "B2", "B3", 
"B4", "B5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"), amount = c(4844.5, 
8601, 8518.4, 6469.55, 7804.53333333333, 4650.4, 5355.25, 5796.7, 
4899.25, 4995, 10151.38, 14484.8666666667, 9910.06666666667, 
10507.35, 9644.2), duration = c(1.48475, 3.675, 5.399, 6.9995, 
10.9613333333333, 1.8655, 3.493, 4.552, 6.3235, 7.884, 1.8558, 
3.55, 5.32466666666667, 7.01975, 12.6736666666667)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .Names = c("date", 
"country", "bucket", "amount", "duration"))
```

EXTRA: as Jimbou showed, grouping is working but my function is somehow broken. Hard coding some variables will get this working, so I just need to figure out correct variable reference on those?

```
weights_fun1 <- function(objective, constraint){
  lp.mod <- make.lp(0, 5)
  set.objfn(lp.mod, objective)
  lp.control(lp.mod,sense="max")
  add.constraint(lp.mod, constraint, "=", 6)
  add.constraint(lp.mod, rep(1, 5), "=", 1)
  set.bounds(lp.mod, upper = rep(0.4, 5))
  set.bounds(lp.mod, lower = rep(0.10, 5))
  solve(lp.mod)
  weights <- round(get.variables(lp.mod), 4)
  return(weights)
}

three_groups %>% 
  group_by(date, country) %>% 
  mutate(weights = weights_fun1(amount, duration))

# A tibble: 15 x 6
# Groups:   date, country [3]
         date country bucket    amount  duration weights
       <date>   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2006-01-31      AT     B1  4844.500  1.484750  0.1000
 2 2006-01-31      AT     B2  8601.000  3.675000  0.1911
 3 2006-01-31      AT     B3  8518.400  5.399000  0.4000
 4 2006-01-31      AT     B4  6469.550  6.999500  0.1000
 5 2006-01-31      AT     B5  7804.533 10.961333  0.2089
 6 2006-01-31      AU     B1  4650.400  1.865500  0.1000
 7 2006-01-31      AU     B2  5355.250  3.493000  0.1000
 8 2006-01-31      AU     B3  5796.700  4.552000  0.1235
 9 2006-01-31      AU     B4  4899.250  6.323500  0.2765
10 2006-01-31      AU     B5  4995.000  7.884000  0.4000
11 2006-01-31      BE     B1 10151.380  1.855800  0.1000
12 2006-01-31      BE     B2 14484.867  3.550000  0.4000
13 2006-01-31      BE     B3  9910.067  5.324667  0.1000
14 2006-01-31      BE     B4 10507.350  7.019750  0.2136
15 2006-01-31      BE     B5  9644.200 12.673667  0.1864
```

Comment: I had a similar problem recently with a custom function and grouped data., My solution was to use the data.table package instead, which worked just fine. So if you just want to get your weights done, I suggest you try data.table, but this doesnt answer you question obviously.

Comment: ok, let's see if this is something that will get solved. I'm moving from punch of packages to tidyverse, because don't want to load different packages all the time. Thanks for info though.

Comment: Can you change your function to something like this: `weights_fun <- function(x,y) mean(x)/mean(y);
three_groups %>% 
  group_by(date, country) %>% 
  mutate(weights = weights_fun(amount, duration))`

Comment: That seems to work, giving different weights column for each group. So my function is somehow broken, even if its working for one? My references are somehow broken I guess?

Comment: It is broken when using it in `mutate` or `summarise`. Please have a look [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). Try to use `!!` and `quo`

Comment: Thanks, I think all I need to do is to find someway to count rows in each of my group to get this work and replace those hardcoded 5s' with that. As my data will have different number of rows between groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer to my own question, but this seems to be work around and just poor tidyverse knowledge from my part. Thanks to Jimbou. Better answers are welcome.

modified function:

```
weights_fun1 <- function(objective, constraint, rows){
  lp.mod <- make.lp(0, rows[1])
  set.objfn(lp.mod, objective)
  lp.control(lp.mod,sense="max")
  add.constraint(lp.mod, constraint, "=", 6)
  add.constraint(lp.mod, rep(1, rows[1]), "=", 1)
  set.bounds(lp.mod, upper = rep(0.4, rows[1]))
  set.bounds(lp.mod, lower = rep(0.10, rows[1]))
  solve(lp.mod)
  weights <- round(get.variables(lp.mod), 4)
  return(weights)
}

three_groups %>% 
  group_by(date, country) %>% 
  mutate(rows = n()) %>% #create helper column, as couldn't figure out other way now
  mutate(weights = weights_fun1(amount, duration, rows))


# A tibble: 15 x 7
# Groups:   date, country [3]
         date country bucket    amount  duration  rows weights
       <date>   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
 1 2006-01-31      AT     B1  4844.500  1.484750     5  0.1000
 2 2006-01-31      AT     B2  8601.000  3.675000     5  0.1911
 3 2006-01-31      AT     B3  8518.400  5.399000     5  0.4000
 4 2006-01-31      AT     B4  6469.550  6.999500     5  0.1000
 5 2006-01-31      AT     B5  7804.533 10.961333     5  0.2089
 6 2006-01-31      AU     B1  4650.400  1.865500     5  0.1000
 7 2006-01-31      AU     B2  5355.250  3.493000     5  0.1000
 8 2006-01-31      AU     B3  5796.700  4.552000     5  0.1235
 9 2006-01-31      AU     B4  4899.250  6.323500     5  0.2765
10 2006-01-31      AU     B5  4995.000  7.884000     5  0.4000
11 2006-01-31      BE     B1 10151.380  1.855800     5  0.1000
12 2006-01-31      BE     B2 14484.867  3.550000     5  0.4000
13 2006-01-31      BE     B3  9910.067  5.324667     5  0.1000
14 2006-01-31      BE     B4 10507.350  7.019750     5  0.2136
15 2006-01-31      BE     B5  9644.200 12.673667     5  0.1864
```